# How to add Realm Object class into RLMArray

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have a Person class which inherits Realm Object and it gets data from API server

```
class Person: Object {
    dynamic var id: Int = 0
    dynamic var email: String? = ""
    dynamic var name: String = ""

    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }

    init(_id: Int, _email: String?, _name: String) {
        id = _id
        email = _email
        name = _name
        super.init()
    }

    required init() {
        super.init()
    }
    required init(realm: RLMRealm, schema: RLMObjectSchema) {
        super.init(realm: realm, schema: schema)
    }

    required init(value: AnyObject, schema: RLMSchema) {
        super.init(value: value, schema: schema)
    }
}
```

On the other hand, I also have an endpoint which returns a NSArray of Person class instances, and I want to map the data to Persons class like below.

```
class Persons: Object {
    var persons: RLMArray = RLMArray(objectClassName: "Person")

    init(_persons: [Person]?) {
        let personsRLMArray = RLMArray(objectClassName: "Person")
        if _persons != nil {
            for person in _persons! {
                personsRLMArray.addObject(person)
            }
        }
        persons = personsRLMArray
        super.init()
    }

    required init() {
        super.init()
    }
    required init(realm: RLMRealm, schema: RLMObjectSchema) {
        super.init(realm: realm, schema: schema)
    }

    required init(value: AnyObject, schema: RLMSchema) {
        super.init(value: value, schema: schema)
    }
}
```

Since this endpoint returns NSArray, not RLMArray, I need to declare a RLMArray and add each element of the NSArray into the RLMArray in the init.

Then I get an error like, 
"Cannot convert value of type 'Person' to expected argument type 'RLMObject' "

If I change the Person's parent class to RLMObject, not Object, the error disappears but I'm not sure it is the right way to do. 
Is there any other way to avoid this kind of error?

There're lots of similar questions but I couldn't find the same one.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Realm with Swift you should use `List<Object>` instead of `RLMArray`. So correct syntax would be:

```
var persons = List<Person>()
persons.append(somePerson)
```

`List<Object>` behaves as native Swift `Array`. It is mutable and you can use functional methods on it to filter or map the data.

If you need more info on Realm lists I suggest [checking this out](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#to-many-relationships).